# Spotify API search VS in-app search

Tags: spotify, spotify-desktop

I'm working on tracks search and I found that in-app search performs spellchecking of query. For example for query 'seaman rammstein' result will be 1 song Seemann by Rammstein, but search via API(https://api.spotify.com/v1/search) has no items.
And I wonder what method or params are used in application search?
Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

you're correct that the Search API doesn't do what we call "fuzzy matching". There is an open issue on the Web API issue tracker that you can follow [here](https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues/244).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you use third-party software for fuzzy matching or this is your inner feature?

Comment: I have no idea :)